# Rejecting unlisted senders in Postfix

Tags: email, postfix, email-server

A question from a beginner Postfix admin.
What is the exact difference between writing in `main.cf`:

```
smtpd_reject_unlisted_sender = yes
```

and

```
smtpd_sender_restrictions =
    reject_unlisted_sender
```

?

Is there a real difference in operation or is `smtpd_reject_unlisted_sender` just a way to enforce this restriction when some of rules listed in `smtpd_sender_restrictions` results in `PERMIT` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first option apply to all local senders, the second permit to have a criteria like:

```
smtpd_sender_restrictions =
    check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/acl_unknown_permited
    reject_unlisted_sender
```

on file /etc/postfix/acl_unknown_permited

```
nonexistent@example.com permit
```

The 'permit' inside /etc/postfix/acl_unknown_permited make restriction process jump to smtpd_recipient_restriction without process reject_unlisted_sender. The right hand of file support a acl list, like:

```
nonexistent@example.com permit_mynetworks, reject
```

This create many possiblilities.

Comment: Is there anything `smtpd_reject_unlisted_sender` can do which `smtpd_sender_restrictions` can't? -- And I would really like to see the question answered...

Comment: the first enable globally (this is commonly used) the sender validation from local domains, but in specific cases can be used as acl in smtpd restrictions.

Comment: Neither did you answer OP's question, nor mine.

Comment: The answer is "No".